# vector-matrix-vector equation solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

if $w^TKw=r$, where $w$ is vector (unknown variable) and $K$ is matrix, can we derive $w$? (i.e., get the $f$ for $w=f(K,r)$)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: No, e.g.  If $K$ is a singular matrix, and $w$ is a vector from $K$'s kernel then you cannot conclude from the result $0=w^TKw$ what the vector $w$ has been.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n w_j\,K_{jk}\,w_k = r$$ Generally you will have one multivariate quadratic polynomial. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153436/can-you-efficiently-solve-a-system-of-quadratic-multivariate-polynomials/153469#153469